# How to parse data from xml files written for flash in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I made some flash files(.xml) for my online website. Now i want that data in those xml files for my android app. how can i achieve that. The xml files are pretty much in good format, neat and properly written.
Here is a little code of that xml file which is pretty much same in all others also.thnx in advance.

```
<slide id="2" template="listeningStayMultiText">
    <images>
        <image direction="Right" xCord="100" yCord="170"><![CDATA[images/common/1x1.gif]]></image>
    </images>
    <sentences>
        <sentence index="1"  fontColor="0x000000"  width="600" height="70" size="18" xPos="50" yPos="20" bgColor="0xDBEFDF" borderColor="0x006600" align="left"><![CDATA[<br/>  Let’s look at how we make negative sentences in the simple present tense -]]></sentence>
        <sentence index="2"  fontColor="0xffffff"  width="300" height="60" size="18" xPos="50" yPos="100" bgColor="0x006600" borderColor="0x000000" align="center"><![CDATA[<br/>POSITIVE SENTENCE]]></sentence>
        <sentence index="3"  fontColor="0xffffff"  width="300" height="60" size="18" xPos="350" yPos="100" bgColor="0x006600" borderColor="0x000000" align="center"><![CDATA[<br/>NEGATIVE SENTENCE]]></sentence>
        <sentence index="4"  fontColor="0x000000"  width="300" height="120" size="18" xPos="50" yPos="160" bgColor="0xDBEFDF" borderColor="0x000000" align="center"><![CDATA[<br/>I play football]]></sentence>
        <sentence index="5"  fontColor="0x000000"  width="300" height="120" size="18" xPos="350" yPos="160" bgColor="0xDBEFDF" borderColor="0x000000" align="center"><![CDATA[<br/>I <b>do not</b> play football<br/>OR<br/>I <b>don't</b> play football]]></sentence>
        <sentence index="6"  fontColor="0x000000"  width="600" height="90" size="18" xPos="50" yPos="300" bgColor="0xDBEFDF" borderColor="0x000000" align="center"><![CDATA[<br/>We use '<b>do not</b>' or '<b>don’t</b>' with ‘<b>I</b>’ to make negative sentences in the simple present tense.]]></sentence>
    </sentences>
    <audio><![CDATA[images/common/silence.mp3]]></audio>        
    <bgImage><![CDATA[images/bg.jpg]]></bgImage>
</slide>
```

Comment: Use `XmlPullParser`. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Simple framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

It uses annotations with your data model and it very easy to implement.
In your case it will look like

```
@Root
public class Slide {
    @Attribute
    public int id;
    @Attribute
    public String template;
    @ElementList
    public List<Images> image;
    @ElementList
    public List<Sentence> sentences;

}
```

etc...